# Como eliminar caracteres especiales en php

Tags: php, str-replace

Quiero eliminar unos caracteres especiales de un resultado de esta consulta, esta es la consulta:

```
$permiso = DB::table('personal_access_tokens')->select('abilities')->where('tokenable_id',$id)->get();
```

El resultado de esta consulta es en formato json:

```
[
  {
    "abilities": "[\"rol:user\"]"
  }
]
```

Y pensé que la funcion str_replace() podría ser mi solución, para elimitar todo lo demás y solo dejar 'rol:user', asi que lo aplique.

```
$resultado = str_replace('{["\"/:abilities','',$permiso);
```

Este fue mi resultado:

```
"[{\"abilities\":\"[\\\"rol:user\\\"]\"}]"
```

Lo que quiero es que solo quede: rol:user

Informacion adicional:

Resultado de:

$permiso = json_decode($permiso,true);

$resultado = var_dump($permiso);

```
   array(1){
  [
    0
  ]=>array(1){
    [
      "abilities"
    ]=>string(12)"["rol: user"]"
  }
}{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con

`json_decode($permiso);`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, no me funciono me muestra el mismo resultado

Comment: Podrías hacerle un var_dump a la variable por favor?

Comment: Si, ya actualice la pregunta.

Comment: Si, pero hazle un var_dump($permiso) SIENDO $permiso = json_decode($permiso,true)

Comment: Listo, Ya actualice la pregunta

Comment: Bien, ahora obtienes el string así: $permiso[0]["abilities"]

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono:)

Comment: De nada, recuerda poner esta respuesta como pregunta aceptada si te sirvió.